# Prevent directory listing and force 403 to 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am builiding a website with PrestaShop 1.7.
I have directory structure as:

```
root
 -admin
 -app
 -bin
 -cache...
```

When I type `mysite.com/app/` or `mysite.com/mail/template.html` it shows

> 403 Error Access Forbidden.

But I want to force all errors to be 404 error instead of 403 errors. How can I achieve this? Or are any there other better methods to hide my website website directories?

I created `.htaccess` file in every directory and placed `Options -Indexes`. Still shows generic 403 Access Forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `RedirectMatch` for the specific directories/files you want blocking.

such as:

`RedirectMatch 404 ^/admin(/?|/.*)$
 RedirectMatch 404 ^/app(/?|/.*)$
 RedirectMatch 404 ^/bin(/?|/.*)$
 RedirectMatch 404 ^/mail/template.html$`

This will redirect matches of that directory or any sub-directories/file contained (i.e. /app/foo/bar.php)

Comment: Is this the best (secured) approach? Because I am working on eCommerce website. Should I add these to the main `.htaccess` file or in each `.htaccess` file in each directory?